# React how to manage props from parent inside children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Directly to the question:

I have 2 components that are using the same data (props from parent component) and I need to change the props value from the children component and see changes inside his parent component. Example below

```
const User = ({ badges }) => {
  <BadgesFilter context={badges} />
  {badges.map(badge => (
    <Badge badge={badge} />
  ))}
}
```

`<BadgesFilter />` - simple component that only filtering badges in example `badges.filter(badge => badge.name.includes(searchingBadge))`

I'm not sure how can I implement it.

Comment: you define a callback function in the top level component and pass it down to children

Answer (score 0):

Define the props in `useState` hook in the parent component. Pass the defined `state` and `setState` to both your child components and use `setState` in the child component appropriately to change the state. The changes will reflect across all three components. You can also try `useContext` hook to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would normally define the function(s) for altering the parent state in the parent and pass them also as props to the children. Let's say we have a parent component that has some boolean state, and we want to toggle this value from within a child component whenever a button is clicked. We would have something like this:

```js
type ChildProps = {
  onButtonClick: () => void;
};

const ChildComponent: FunctionComponent<ChildProps> = (props) => {
  return <button onClick={props.onButtonClick}>Toggle!</button>;
};

const ParentComponent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [myBool, setMyBool] = useState(false);

  const toggleMyBool = () => setMyBool(!myBool);

  useEffect(() => console.log(myBool), [myBool]);

  return (
    <ChildComponent onButtonClick={toggleMyBool} />
  )
}
```

I also put a `useEffect` hook so that you can visualize the change in the value of `myBool` in the console. It is not necessary to include, it is just for testing purposes to ensure that the value is being correctly updated.

Notice that the names of the functions and the props can be anything you want (I normally follow the convention of specifying to which action the prop name refers to, but you could use something else).

Answer (score 0):

To let a child control (a part of) the parent state you should pass a setter down to the child. This child can then update the parent state using the provided setter.

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="user"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
function User({ initialBadges }) {
  const [badges, setBadges] = React.useState(initialBadges);
  
  // create a setter for each badge, extracting the collection logic
  const badgeSetters = React.useMemo(() => (
    badges.map(({ id }) => (replacement) => {
      replacement = toCallback(replacement);
      setBadges((badges) => (
        badges.map((badge) => badge.id == id ? replacement(badge) : badge)
      ));
    })
  ), [badges]);

  return <>
    <BadgesFilter context={badges} />
    {badges.map((badge, i) => (
      <Badge key={badge.id} badge={badge} setBadge={badgeSetters[i]} />
    ))}
  </>;
}

function BadgesFilter({ context }) {
  return <div>context: {JSON.stringify(context)}</div>;
}

function Badge({ badge, setBadge }) {
  const increment = () => {
    setBadge((badge) => ({ ...badge, value: badge.value + 1 }));
  };
  const decrement = () => {
    setBadge((badge) => ({ ...badge, value: badge.value - 1 }));
  };

  return <div>
    <button type="button" onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    <button type="button" onClick={increment}>+</button>
    {JSON.stringify(badge)}
  </div>;
}

// normalization helper
function toCallback(value) {
  if (typeof value == "function") {
    return value;
  } else {
    return () => value;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <User initialBadges={[{ id: 1, value: 0 }, { id: 2, value: 0 }]} />,
  document.querySelector("#user")
);
</script>
```

The `User` component manages the collection. For this reason I've extracted the collection logic into the `badgeSetters` helper variable. The setter passed to each child can be used as if it needs to update a single object. This simplifies the logic within the child, and also enforces the responsibilities: `User` manages the badges collection, a `Badge` manages only itself.